# How to use same protocol for git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

In a git repository R I have a submodule that I initialized with the following command:

```
git submodule add git@mygitserver...
```

Now a user just cloned R using `https` and get an error when running

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

because he doesn't have ssh (with public key uploaded on the server) access. 
So my question is, is it possible to create a submodule that will automatically uses the same protocol than the one used to clone the parent repository on the `git submodule update` command ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That user can set the config:

```
git config --global url.https://mygitserver/.insteadOf ssh://git@mygitserver/
# or possibly (to be tested)
git config --global url.https://mygitserver/.insteadOf git@mygitserver/
```

That way, https urls will always be used for mygitserver (main repo or submodules), instead of ssh ones.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested in detail (only some cases), but it seems that if your `.gitmodules` file uses relative urls and if the repo is always cloned via a "full url", then things should work:

`.gitmodules`:

```
 [submodule "same_users"]
    path = same_users
    url = ../something.git
 [submodule "other_user"]
    path = same_users
    url = ../../different-user/something.git

 # Maybe even this?
 [submodule "other_server"]
    path = same_users
    url = //git@gitlab.com/joe_r_user/hacks.git
```

Clone:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git ./ssh
cd ssh
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

However if the user chooses `clone git@github.com:user/repo.git` (note the `:`), the `update` won't work.