# Make git fetch submodules using the same protocol as the parent?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a way to set up a repository so that any user that clones it via `ssh` or via `https` will also clone any submodules it contains via the same protocol as they used for the parent?

---

If that is not possible, that fact (preferably with a citation of why that choice was made by the git designers) would be a valid answer.

Things I'm **not** asking for (because I already know them) and which I'd not consider a useful answer:

- Making it always use one or the other
- A way that [a user can override which is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564696/how-to-use-same-protocol-for-git-submodules)

Comment: There is not, but I don't know why they did it that way (other than the obvious "because it was easy").

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this because Git has no intrinsic way of knowing that multiple URLs using different protocols map to the same repository.

For example, the mapping that GitHub uses on its servers is not appropriate for my personal Git server, which uses Gitolite.  Similarly, anonymous access over SSH is usually not provided, so if a user does not have an account on a server, an SSH URL cannot be used.  Git cannot know *a priori* about this configuration.

Git provides the `insteadOf` mapping so that you can override these settings if you like depending on your needs.  The user is presumed to know best about their needs and configuration and about the servers they're accessing.

Comment: I suspect, for the majority of cases, either: 1) the module is on the same server as the referent and thus access control will be the same for both (or at least know able) or 2) they are on different servers and thus absolute paths should be used, at which point the access control of the target server is again knowable. -- Regardless, when it's available, it would seem that a relative URL (path or protocol relative) should be able to be crafted that gets what I want. And where the protocol must be forced, an absolute URL should already be used.

Comment: Git does not support protocol-relative URLs in this case, although we are of course happy to accept a patch.  In the general case what you want to do is not achievable, although of course it can be done with path-relative URLs if you have specialized knowledge about your case.  My answer stands for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ["things just work"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726312/1343) as long as `clone` via ssh access is done using the `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` form rather than the `git@github.com:user/repo.git` form. At least as long as it's all on the same server.

Answer (score -1):

That's Git's usual behavior when the submodules are hosted on the same server as the main repo.  `submodule.somename.url` will be e.g. `../somename.git` in `.gitmodules`, and `git submodule init` will fill in the missing bits from the `origin` url.

Why should anyone expect arbitrary external submodules to be accessible with the same protocol as a local project? Configuring your repos so initial setup fails unless the `origin` protocol works on arbitrary external submodules' servers is just begging for trouble. People who can talk to your project server over `ssh`, are not so likely to have or want `ssh` access elsewhere.

If you want a custom protocol-copying setup, it's like five lines of shell code, it's easier to just write it than to learn some new redundant tweak facility, let alone implement one.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing I would believe `../somename.git` works but `../../someuser/somename.git` does not (it seems to resolve to `~/someuser/somename.git` in the local file system or some such). I *think* what's going on is the SSH URLs put a `:` after the host so the second `../` eats the host and whatnot along with the intended component. -- As to why: I'd expect that respecting the users choices default would be a good enough reason to allow that.